# Sychronizing a List and a Term Set

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, managed-metadata, managed-navigation, synchronisation

In an application I'm building in SP 2013, I would like to have several lists with lookup fields, attachments, workflows, etc., but also be able to reference them via tag fields (at least like a managed metadata field) and have them accessible via friendly URLs.

Except for developing significant coded assemblies (to reinvent the wheel)...

- As far as I understand, attachments, multiple views, list view web parts, workflows, and several other features are only possible to develop with lists
- As far as I understand, friendly URLs, "tagging", modifying via the term store management tool (of course), and probably other things are only possible using managed metadata

I have an idea to set up event receivers to synchronize these several lists with a corresponding set of terms in the term store, which are then synchronized (and linked via navigation) back to their appropriate lists (most likely via an event receiver on the TaxonomyHiddenList).

I don't expect to have to worry about items or modification outside of the Web Application.

Is this a bad idea? A good idea? What are the most significant issues, other than having duplicated data that might somehow fall out of synchronization and that it's probably not really supported by Microsoft?

**EDIT**: For the sake of clarity, I would use the event receiver(s) on TaxonomyHiddenList only to trigger the synchronization (which would then use the taxonomy API to actually sync), in an effort to reduce the chances of Microsoft making a breaking change.